# Existing standard functor/function to check equality to 0?

Tags: c++, stl, c++98

I want to count the number of `0` in a vector of unsigned long integers. Is there an existing standard function/functor to pass to `std::count_if` ? Or have I to write it myself like this example ?

```
class is_equal
{
  private:
    unsigned long int v;
  public:
    is_equal(unsigned long int value) : v(value) {}
    bool operator () (unsigned long int x) { return x == this->v; }
};

unsigned long int count_zero(const std::vector<unsigned long int>& data)
{
  return std::count_if(data.begin(), data.end(), is_equal(0));
}
```

**Note :** I don't use C++11 for compatibility reason.

Comment: You can just use [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) with a single value.

Comment: what about `std::equal_to` with `std::bind2nd`?

Comment: You mean like [`std::equal_to`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to)? But it's better to simply use `std::count` as already suggested.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah: ain't `std::bind2nd` considered to be deprecated?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah `bind2nd` is deprecated.

Comment: @Bathsheba it is deprecated in C++11 but he isn't using that.  Anyway, The suggestion to use std::count is better if he really does want equality.  I was assuming that he was asking a general question where he might want other comparators...

Comment: Yet again I don't understand the question downvote. It (i) is well written (ii) has some relevant code, and (iii) their ain't a dupe screaming out for attention.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah `rand()` isn't deprecated yet it is a horrible function.

Comment: @sleeptightpupper  I agree.  And bind2nd is a horrible function too.  I would rather write my own functor than to use bind2nd but he asked if there was an standard alternative...  I shouldn't have said anything.

Comment: God! How can I forget `std::count` ? However, I let the question open, I'm interested in the existence of such simple functors in the standard lib.

Comment: For completion, the whole line would be: `std::count_if(data.begin(), data.end(), std::bind2nd(std::equal_to<unsigned long int>(), 0));` Although I also discourage std::bind2nd

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::count(data.begin(), data.end(), v);` would do it. (Although if the vector is *sorted* you can get the result out in O(Log N) using `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound`).

You just need to make sure that `v` is *exactly* the same type as the vector element - unless you tell the compiler which template instantiation you want to use.

Comment: `equal_to` would be better in the general case as it will deduce the types automatically, but in this case `count` is better.